# Moq.MockRepository.Of() usage when method has void return

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am using Moq's MockRepository.Of<> method to mock various methods to test. When I chain multiple methods setups together via the Where clause it works when the mocked methods have a return. This is obviously due to the Where requiring a boolean expression. Can you use this pattern to setup the mock for a method that doesn't have a return variable?

```
var mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
var debitCardBinManager = mockRepository.Of<IDebitCardBinManager>()
                .Where(mgr => mgr.GetEffectiveDateBuffer() == 35)
                .Where(mgr => mgr.AddAction(It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
                .First();
```

From this example the GetEffectiveDateBuffer method can be setup this way because it returns an integer. However the AddAction can't because it has a void return (compile error is can't convert 'void' to 'bool'). I would however like to get it setup via pattern. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the Where for AddAction method since it has a void return type. If you change the MockBehaviour to Loose then it will automatically mock the method but if you are looking to verify on that method it won't work.

Comment: Thanks. I do want Strict behavior and to verify that method. So it looks like I'll have to use the MockRepository.Create method and call Setup for each.